# How to suppress the `commit <SHA1>` from git rev-list

Tags: git

When I do `git rev-list --pretty='%h %an' master..HEAD` I got

```
d9ce4ce Daniel Hilst
commit 4039e974491f12d102dec535c818880a354169fa
4039e97 Daniel Hilst
commit 303b7a5dca5036121c476f42313f46a53a8da16c
303b7a5 Daniel Hilst
```

I expected to `commit <SHA1>` to be suppressed when I use my own `--pretty`.

Of course I can `| grep -v commit` but that is not what I'm asking for. I want to know if there is one way to  make `git` suppress this. (Just to be clear). It may be another git command, maybe...

Comment: Are you looking for `git log --pretty='%h %an' master..HEAD`?

Comment: It's almost always wrong to combine `git rev-list` with `--pretty=...` or `--format=...`. The `log` and `rev-list` commands are basically just one big command, with formatting directives only useful when run as `git log`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

Ryan can you post it so I can mark it the right answer?